# How to look for a problem with low RPS in VisualVM?

Tags: java, spring, testing, jmeter, jvm

There was a problem with the high response time of my Spring application.

My colleagues advised me to use VisualVM, simultaneously running the load using Jmeter. I want to check which method takes the most time

However, in VisualVM I get an uninformative answer - there are no methods of my application.

Can you tell me if I'm going the right way and how to display information on methods inside the application?
[image]

Comment: Low response time is good. Do you mean high?

Comment: typo, I meant a high response time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to go for a more comprehensive tool like [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) or an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) if you have an appropriate license (there are free and open source like [Apache Skywalking](https://skywalking.apache.org/) as  well)

Theoretically it's possible to use JVisualVM however it's better to go for the "snapshot" mode, check out [Profiling With VisualVM](http://web.archive.org/web/20190117031705/https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/profiling-with-visualvm,-part-1) article series for instructions.

You can also get some [JMX](https://www.baeldung.com/java-management-extensions) metrics using [JMeter's PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)